# Serialize Boolean to String Y or N in GSON

Tags: android, json, gson

I've tried this code to Serialize/Deserialize json to gson and vice versa

```java
public class BooleanSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Boolean>, JsonDeserializer<Boolean> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Boolean src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(src?"Y":"N");
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        return json.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Y");
    }
}
```

And used this class like this

```java
BooleanSerializer booleanSerializer = new BooleanSerializer();
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Boolean.class, booleanSerializer);
        gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Boolean.class, booleanSerializer);
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
Event event = gson.fromJson(eventJObj.toString(), Event.class);
```

Model class is like this

```java
public class Event implements Parcelable {
    private long eventID;
    private String objective;
    private String typeOfEvent;
    private Boolean isBookmarked;
    private Boolean iAttended;
    private Boolean isFeatured;
}
```

And json format is like this

```
{
"eventID": 25,
"objective": "event",
"typeOfEvent": "conference",
"isBookmarked": "N",
"iAttended": "Y",
"isFeatured": "Y",
}
```

When I try to convert the above json to the Event object, It failed to convert Y to `true` it always holds the value `false`. Additionally, for some reason, it is compulsory to extend the parcelable class for `Event` object.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the mistake. In `deserialize` method in `BooeleanSerializer` class was the culprit.

```java
public class BooleanSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Boolean>, JsonDeserializer<Boolean> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Boolean src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(src?"Y":"N");
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        // return json.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Y"); // Wrong code
        return "Y".equalsIgnoreCase(json.getAsString()); 
       // json.getAsString() is the right way to get json element value
    }
}
```